# Add Custom Error Message to VF Page

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension

I am trying to add a custom error message to a VF page.  My controller saves, but when I save my VF page without the checkbox field being checked, it saves anyway and bypasses the error condition in my controller.  What am I doing wrong?

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote__c" extensions="QuoteExtController">
<apex:messages/>
<apex:form >
    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
    <apex:pageblock>
        Quote Name: <apex:InputField value="{!Quote__c.Name}"/>
        Quote Check: <apex:InputField value="{!Quote__c.Must_Be_Checked__c}"/>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller Extension:

```
public with sharing class QuoteExtController {
    private quote__c quote;

    public QuoteExtController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.quote = (Quote__c)stdController.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference onSave() {
        if(quote.Must_Be_Checked__c==TRUE) {
            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new  ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Check field');
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg); 
            return null;
        } else if (quote.Id != null) {
            insert quote;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would advise `<apex:pageMessages/>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command button is calling the standard controller save. You need to use your custom action in the save button, shown below:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!onSave}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. I knew it was going to be some dumb error on my part.

Comment: I've been there too - sometimes you just need an extra set of eyes!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using `Quote__c` in your page, and not your `quote` page property.

Change your VF markup to use this:

```
<apex:pageblock >

  Quote Name: <apex:InputField value="{!quote.Name}"/>
  Quote Check: <apex:InputField value="{!quote.Must_Be_Checked__c}"/>
</apex:pageblock>
```

And finally, make sure you're calling your custom `onSave` method and not the standard Save method.

Comment: That call to `addFields` is not valid syntax. `Quote__c` and `Quote` as shown here are referring to the same object instance, which should have those fields populated due to their use in the body of the Visualforce page.

Comment: I agree it's kinda weird that they are using a custom object for quote but I don't think that's the root of the issue and there very well may be a reason for it. I'd advise sticking to the topic at hand.